# BackButton event closes the app Windows 10 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

I am currently developing an app for Windows 10. I want to implement a back button event on my app. When I press the back button on the Frame1, the app closes, which as I wanted to do. When I am at the Frame2, and navigate to Frame3, and I press the back button, the app closes itself.

What I want is the back button event on Frame3 make the Frame3 go back to Frame2, and when I press the back button on Frame2, terminates the app.

## On my App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Frame1), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

## On my Frame1.xaml.cs :

```
private void 1_BackRequested(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame frame1 = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (frame1 != null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Application.Current.Exit();
        }
    }
```

## On my Frame2.xaml.cs :

```
private void 2_BackRequested(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame frame2= Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (frame2 != null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Application.Current.Exit();
        }
    }
```

## On my Frame3.xaml.cs :

```
private void 3_BackRequested(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame frame3= Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (frame3.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            frame3.GoBack();
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the event handlers you added to BackPressed event will fire in FIFO order, so your event handles stack according to your code is that:

When you are in Page1:

> 1.Close app

When you navigate to Page2:

> 1.Close app
>
> 2.Close app

When you navigate to Page3 from Page2:

> 1.Close app
>
> 2.Close app
>
> 3.Goback to the last page

So when you press back button in Page3, the first handler should fired first, which means that it `close app` instead of `going back` to the last page.

So how to fix this?

In your each page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }
```

That means whenever you leave this page, you unregister the Backpressed event and when you enter a page you register a new one to make it work.

Comment: you know what @JuniperPhoton ? THANK YOU ^^ IT WORKED